# Flowplayer is not on top

Tags: html, css, flash, flowplayer

I have a problem because flowplayer is displayed behind my div

My div code :

```
#lights {
position:fixed;
top:0px;
left:0px;
background-color:black;
opacity:0.9;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

I tried countless solutions(from changing wmode params) to changing `z-index` values of player and `#lights` div.

Anyone knows what could be wrong? and how could I place flowplayer over `#lights`?

Comment: Please post a little more of the relevant code or make a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

z-index can only be applied on fixed and absolute position element. It could be that your player

- doesn't have a fixed or absolute position
- is inside a container which has lower z-index value

Comment: I added position:relative to player and that solved it.Thanks